# CakePHP find statement for a sql query involving two models

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, find

I am new to cake and I am practicing with a twitter-like clone.  At this point, I have 3 tables:

`users (id, name)`

- id is the auto-generated id
- name of the user

`tweets (id, content, user_id)`

- id is the auto-generated id
- content is the text of the tweet
- user_id is the id of the user that made the post

`followers (id, follower_id, following_id)`

- id is the auto-generated id
- follower_id is the user who is doing the following
- following_id is the user that is being followed

So, being new to sql as well, I tried to test some sql queries against my db with this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets 
WHERE user_id IN
(SELECT following_id FROM followers WHERE follower_id = 1)  <--- this 1 is just a magic number to test out the query
```

In this query, I'm trying to find all the tweets of those users that are being followed by user (with id of 1)

My question is sort of two-fold.  For the life of me, I can't find out how to make an equivalent find query in cake.  Secondly, my sql query involves looking at two tables, so in effect, over two cakephp Models.  I'm not sure how to use two models from one controller to construct this find query.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions
look for sub queries section

Comment: thank you, but I still find it so hard to understand.  Additionally, using a find subquery, is it possible to paginate the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conditionsSubQuery['`followers`.`follower_id `'] = 1;
$dbo = $this->Follower->getDataSource();

$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(    
    array(        
        'fields' => array('`followers`.`following_id`'),
            'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->Follower), 
           'alias' => 'followers', 
           'limit' => null,  
          'offset' => null, 
           'joins' => array(),  
          'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
            'order' => null,  
          'group' => null    ),

        $this->Follower);



    $subQuery = ' `tweets`.`user_id` IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';

    $subQueryExpression = $dbo->expression($subQuery);

   $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;

   $this->Tweet->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this, but I got this error: 

SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'tweets.user_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

I verified that those are the correct database & table names.  Would there be another reason why this might arise?

Comment: I fixed it by making this line:

 $subQuery = '`user_id` IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';

Thank you!!!