# CakePHP Paginate() the results from a find subquery?

Tags: php, cakephp, subquery, pagination

This is a follow-up to an earlier question here: [CakePHP find statement for a sql query involving two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642726/cakephp-find-statement-for-a-sql-query-involving-two-models)

I wasn't sure whether to add it on to there, but I figured this is a new question in itself.  My apologies if this isn't correct!

Given a cakephp find subquery, is it possible to use paginate() on the results of the find?  from the cake documentation, it seems that the paginate() function only works on Models, not on an array of data.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!  How does one perform pagination on a set of data like an array of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have all the data in the array, I suggest output all that to your page (not the same as showing all the data) and use javascript to paginate it (just use a javascript grid plugin out there): more responsive app and less load on the server.